# How to solve `permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()` when migrating from Spring Security OAuth2 to Keycloak?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am currently migrating from Spring Security OAuth2 to Keycloak (after the Spring Security team's decision to deprecate the Spring Security OAuth2 project) but I am stuck with this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$330.00000000ED7F64A0.getObject(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
```

I have 10 microservices to migrate, I defined a `common` jar which contains all configurations. This is the Keycloak configuration in `common`:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true )
@KeycloakConfiguration
@Import( KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.class )
public class CommonsKeycloakSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(); // Equivalent to @EnableResourceServer in S.S. OAuth2
    super.configure( http );
}


@Autowired
public void configureGlobal( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) {

    SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
    grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix( "ROLE_" ); 
    grantedAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase( true );

    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper( grantedAuthorityMapper );
    auth.authenticationProvider( keycloakAuthenticationProvider );
}

@Value("${spring.application.name}"
public String APP_NAME;

@Bean
public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategyPorvider() {
    return APP_NAME.equals( "securityservice")
            ? new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy( new SessionRegistryImpl() )
            : new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
}

@Bean
@DependsOn( "sessionAuthenticationStrategyPorvider" )
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return sessionAuthenticationStrategyPorvider();
}

@Bean
@Scope( scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )
public KeycloakSecurityContext provideKeycloakSecurityContext() {
    ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    Principal principal = requireNonNull( attributes ).getRequest().getUserPrincipal();
    if ( principal == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    if ( principal instanceof KeycloakAuthenticationToken ) {
        principal = (Principal) ( (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) principal ).getPrincipal();
    }
    if ( principal instanceof KeycloakPrincipal ) {
        return ( (KeycloakPrincipal) principal ).getKeycloakSecurityContext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

And properties in `common/src/main/resources/application.yml`:

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: "" #defined in application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml
  realm: ${project.name}
  resource: ${spring.application.name}
  credentials:
    secret: ${application.kck.secret} 
  use-resource-role-mappings: true
  ssl-required: 'none'
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
```

The `common.jar` is then imported in all other microservices. In `productservice` I have defined these specifique http security rules:

```
@Configuration
@Order( 1 )
public class UIResourceProtection extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { // Note that I use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter instead of KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 

    @Override
    public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( STATELESS );
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers( "/ui/product/**" )
                .and()
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/ui/product/private").hasRole( "USER" )
                .antMatchers( HttpMethod.PUT, "/ui/product/public" ).hasRole( "USER" )
                .antMatchers( HttpMethod.GET, ""/ui/product/cost"","/ui/product/public").authenticated()
                .antMatchers( HttpMethod.GET, "/ui/product/public/{id}" ).authenticated()
                .antMatchers( "/ui/product/public/dashboard" ).hasRole( "USER" );                    
    }
}
```

And another one in the same project (i-e: `productservice`)

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Order( 2 )
public class SelfResourceProtection extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { // Note that I use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter instead of KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 

    @Override
    public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/product/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( HttpMethod.GET, "/product/update-db" ).hasRole( "ADMIN" )
                .antMatchers( HttpMethod.GET, "/product/private/{id}" ).permitAll();     
    }
}
```

When I start `productservice` with that configuration I have the exception above: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: permitAll only works with HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()`

After changing configuration parameters, the exception is still thrown.

Any idea how to solve it?

Dependencies version :

```
Spring Boot : 2.2.4.RELEASE
Keycloak : 8.0.1
Spring Security: 5.2.1.RELEASE
Spring Security OAuth2 Resource Server: 5.2.1.RELEASE
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception is caused by the class `CommonsKeycloakSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.
If you look at the source code for `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which you are extending, you will notice that part of the configuration states

```
.logoutUrl("/sso/logout").permitAll()
```

In order for `permitAll()` to be applied, Spring Security expects `authorizeRequests()` to be configured.

Since there is no such configuration in `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, you will need to add an `authorizeRequests()` block to your custom configuration that extends it.

Comment: Thanks, in fact it seems the cause of the issue but I don't understand why Spring Security throws exception from that configuration since their api is planned to be used like that. Strange strange. I simply removed the call to `super.configure(http)`. My configuration does not work yet but I can go ahead now. Thanks

Comment: @akuma8, Spring Security is not intended to be used as you describe (calling `permitAll` without calling `authorizeRequests`). `permitAll` describes an access condition, and `authorizeRequests` is what tells Spring Security to make access decisions. Without `authorizeRequests`, there is nothing configured to actually enforce access conditions. Keycloak is expecting you to call `authorizeRequests`, as outlined in their docs: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#spring-security-configuration

Comment: @jzheaux Sorry for the issue opened in github but it's a bit frustrating to turn arround without knowing what's happening. So the problem come from Keycloak configuration? You suggest me this `I'm wondering why you are using the Keycloak adapter in this case? Since Keycloak's authorization server is compliant with several OAuth 2.0 RFCs, I'd imagine that using Spring Security native would do the trick `. My question is how can I use Spring Security native with Keycloak? With Spring Security OAuth2 it seems clear to me but with S.S. 5.2.1.RELEASE it's not clear at all. I don't see how. Thanks

Comment: @akuma8 No problem. Let's see if we can split the two convos for simplicity. I think your posted question here is already answered, so maybe let's not post here unless it's about the original question.

Comment: @jzheaux Right I’ll contact you on Gitter, I hope you will be there. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers().permitAll()

use authorizeRequests not authorizeHttpRequests

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).